# How to avoid repetition when multiplying and with the correct .replace

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have some data and I want to replace the points `...` with `Nan`.

But when I multiply the column `['Cost']` then `'Nan'` also increases:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},
                   {'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': 2.50},
                   {'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': '...'}],
                  index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
df.replace ('...', 'Nan', inplace =True)
df['Cost']*=10
df
```

How to make numbers just multiply?

Comment: If you complicate the task and use 
'import re' 
'^.\S+'
That with this you can think of

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a string  but use `np.NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

A string can be multiplied (well, better to say "repeated" when multiplied):

```
>>> 'nan' * 10
'nannannannannannannannannannan'
```

But you want the "number" `nan`:

```
>>> float('nan') * 10
nan
```

So replace with the `float` `nan`:

```
>>> df.replace ('...', float('nan'), inplace =True)
>>> df['Cost']*=10
>>> df
          Cost Item Purchased   Name
Store 1  225.0         Sponge  Chris
Store 1   25.0   Kitty Litter  Kevyn
Store 2    NaN          Spoon  Filip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read your data from CSV file and getting `'...'`, then the easiest way to deal with that would be to instruct [Pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) that `'...'` is `NaN` value, using `na_values` parameter:

```
na_vals = ['...', '', '#N/A', '#N/A N/A', '#NA', '-1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '-NaN', '-nan', '1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', 'N/A', 'NA', 'NULL']
df = pd.read_csv(..., na_values=na_vals)
```